# How to migrate OmniDocs to SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, migration

How to migrate NewGen Omnidocs DMS data to SharePoint online 
Pl suggest me how to migrate Omnidocs DMS data to SharePoint.
Any tools or another way?

Answer (score 1):

You can also migrate to a reliable DMS like EisenVault. Its easy and they have a RPA tool to help migrate documents and meta data too

Comment: Details are here:https://www.eisenvault.com/post/migrating-to-eisenvault-from-other-dms-software

Answer (score 0):

You can use client side APIs to replicate data from NewGen Omnidocs DMS to SharePoint Online. For detailed information, you can refer to this post:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ad4935f8-d011-446d-a1ca-084e4dded976/how-to-migrate-newgen-omnidocs-dms-to-sharepoint-online?forum=SP2016